# Using Vitest to test a SvelteKit REST API

Tags: typescript, sveltekit, vitest

I want to write unit tests for a REST API running with SvelteKit but most of the resources are dedicated to test svelte components. I also wanted to avoid Playwright since I don't really need browser testing and I would like to avoid all the tool setup, files, etc...

Is there a clear setup to test an SvelteKit REST API?
Is having the `.test.ts` on the same folder as the route is a good practice?

For now I have a standard SvelteKit skeleton app with the following dir structure:

```
src/
 routes/
  issues/
   +server.ts
   issues.test.ts
```

And I plan to include a `.test.ts` on every API endpoint.

My `vite.config.ts` :

```js
/** @type {import('vite').UserConfig} */
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
    test: {
            include: ['src/**/*.{test,spec}.{js,ts}'],
    },
});
```

And I started with this simple test on `issues.test.ts` :

```js
describe('/issues', () => {
    it('GET', async () => {
        fetch('/issues').then((response) => {
            expect(response.status).toBe(200);
        });
    });

    // ···
});
```

So I realized that I would need the server running so the tests could send the fetch request to an actual place. First I thought that Vitest may manage this automatically but it's not the case. So know I have to run `npm run dev` before running the tests. I find this a bit unconvenient.

Comment: Hello @pau-galopa. I think I have the same question. msw is fine when your api makes outgoing requests that you want to mock, but can you request your own api and check that the response is the one expected? Did you finally sort it out?

Answer (score 0):

the correct way to do API Testing for sveltekit is to use [Playwright test] [1](https://playwright.dev/docs/api-testing#writing-api-test) that you can actually add when you create your Sveltekit project ☺.
Vitest is only used to test functionality and not API published by the server.

You can see it as Vitest only test functionality in your code, and Playwright emulates a whole web system to make what's called [End to end testing](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/end-to-end-testing#:%7E:text=End%2Dto%2Dend%20testing%20is%20a%20type%20of%20testing%20that,and%20meets%20the%20user%20requirements.), that include API Testing.

Hoped it help you !

Answer (score -1):

You can use `msw` with `vitest` to test rest api.
Check this out - https://vitest.dev/guide/mocking.html#requests